# Compare dates yyyy with dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel

In excel is it possible to compare a year yyyy (say 2016) with  date dd/mm/yyyy (say 01/01/2015) and find out which is greater.  My assumption would be that the date in yyyy format will always be the first day of the year.

So for example

```
2015 v 01/01/2014 would return true
2015 v 01/01/2015 would return false
2015 v 01/01/2016 would return false
```

I can code this in VBA but the user needs this in a cell in an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Why this `2015 v 01/01/2014` returns TRUE? Clarify your *assumption*.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to write the VBA code in a function in a code module, that returns the greater value.

```
Public Function CompareDates(date1 AS Date, date2 As Date) As Date
    'Compare date1 and date2
    'CompareDates = whichever date is greater
End Function
```

You can then simply add the formula `=CompareDates(date1, date2)` in the cell

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A1` = `2015` and `B1` = `01/01/2015` you can try:

```
A1=YEAR(B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do you mean something like:**

`=DATE(A1,1,1)>B1`

Assuming your Years are in Column A and Dates are in Column B.